# excel vba arr Intelligent judgment cycle

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

picture

[image]

Column a is copied to column b, and the last cell is transformed

Column b copies column c (analogy), and the cell transformation decreases to the second row for incremental transformation (wavy, the first row does not participate in the transformation)

Special treatment until the last column no longer meets the transformation conditions (w1 unchanged, w2:w6 transformed). The data will only have 1 and 0, the number of input rows in the first column is not limited, I hope the font color and background color will be preserved after transformation

Brief description:
0 becomes 1, 1 becomes 0.
The first row remains unchanged, and the next column is copied from the previous column,
The transformation decreases or increases according to the transformation position in the previous column,
The first round transforms one cell, and the nth round transforms n cells simultaneously

Comment: can you explain this a little bit: what restrictions do you have? "It cannot be implemented normally through for if (technology is limited)"

Comment: Needs more detail - rules are not really clear here.

Comment: 0 transform 1, 1 transform 0. Start from the first column, copy to the second column, transform the last cell, and complete the first operation. Copy the second column to the third column, and transform the last two cells ...

Comment: In the second round, change two cells, and in the third round, change three cells. The first row remains unchanged

Comment: your example is wrong, column L rows 3-4 are not ok

Comment: Wow, that's right. Modify it right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub trans()

    Dim w As Range
    Set w = ActiveSheet.Cells()

    topRow = 6
    bottomRow = 6
    Height = 1
    Direction = -1
    curColumn = 2
    
    Range(w(1, 1), w(6, 1)).Value = 1
    
    While topRow <> 1
        Range(w(1, curColumn - 1), w(6, curColumn - 1)).Copy
        w(1, curColumn).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        For curRow = topRow To bottomRow
            w(curRow, curColumn).Value = Abs(w(curRow, curColumn) - 1)
        Next curRow
        Range(w(topRow, curColumn), w(bottomRow, curColumn)).Select
        Selection.Font.Color = -16776961
        
        With Selection.Interior
            Rem .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
            .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        End With
        
        curColumn = curColumn + 1
        If topRow = 2 And Direction = -1 Or bottomRow = 6 And Direction = 1 Then
            Direction = Direction * -1
            If Direction = -1 And bottomRow = 6 Then
                Height = Height + 1
                topRow = topRow - 1
            End If
        End If
        topRow = topRow + Direction
        bottomRow = topRow + Height - 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Whether the first column can be obtained dynamically instead of the fixed six rows

Comment: @myif corrected with 
    Range(w(1, 1), w(6, 1)).Value = 1

Comment: Can the changed font add a color and background color

Comment: @myif please accept the aswer